# Is a flickery screen bad?

Tags: 14.04, kernel, screen, gpu

I am running 14.04 with the 4.3 kernel (recently updated due to driver issues) and I've noticed a lot of flickery screen things going on. Usually when I scroll or when things update quickly I get a lot of briefly visible horizontal white lines and sometimes a few horizontal lines of ghost images.

I'm not too bothered by it but I want to make sure that theres no possibility that this kernel causing any sort of damage to the screen/gpu.

This is probably a dumb question but I'm a total newbie and figured it couldn't hurt to double check :)

`lshw -c video` gives

```
WARNING: you should run this program as super-user.
*-display               
   description: VGA compatible controller
   product: Intel Corporation
   vendor: Intel Corporation
   physical id: 2
   bus info: pci@0000:00:02.0
   version: 07
   width: 64 bits
   clock: 33MHz
   capabilities: vga_controller bus_master cap_list rom
   configuration: driver=i915 latency=0
   resources: irq:291 memory:de000000-deffffff memory:c0000000-cfffffff ioport:f000(size=64)
```

Comment: It sounds like a driver issue. What graphics do you have?

Comment: @Zacharee1 Do you mean the driver? I guess its i915 but I'm not totally sure what that is.